# Which protocol to use for music streaming?

Tags: networking, streaming, protocols, lan

We wish to write a music streaming app to run on our college LAN. A single user would be able to broadcast an mp3 using this app and all other hosts must be playing it...sort of like a radio.Which of the media streaming protocols are best suited for this purpose?

Comment: I tried to do this at college with a java app and UDP. It worked reasonably well. 

However now days you want one that a mobile phone could just pickup on the network and stream to it.

Answer (score 1):

try using the RTSP 
reference [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol)
or try googling it